# How to transition images within the same image view

Tags: java, android

I am using two ImageViews as a background for my app and its terribly slow so i need to figure a way to transition these images with a fade like transition without using two different ImageViews and simultaneously changing the alpha levels when the button is clicked.

the effect im trying to achieve would be similar to this

```
img1.setAlpha(0.0f);
img2.setAlpha(1.0f);
img1.animate().alpha(0.1f);
img2.animate().alpha(0.0f)
```

but i need to achieve an effect similar to this using only a single imageView and changing the image resources.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible, but there is a viewflipper class that I feel would be a great way to do this. You may also (I saw you dont want to do it, but still) layer an ImageView (the first one) on top of a second Imageview and just slowly fade the first ImageView.

Comment: You have to create your custom `ImageView` and blend two image sources: drawing them both on the `Canvas`.